# Можно ли парсить сайты с помощью selenium на андроид?

Tags: python, парсер, selenium

Если есть такая возможность то как это реализовать? (Небольшие, но полные примеры)

Comment: что затруднило вас найти примеры на том же сайте selenium?

Answer (score 0):

Да, можно использовать библиотеку Selenium для парсинга веб-страниц на устройствах Android. Однако, для этого нужно установить соответствующий драйвер Selenium, который поддерживает работу на мобильных устройствах.

Существует несколько вариантов драйверов Selenium для Android, включая Appium, Selendroid и другие. Для использования Selenium на Android, необходимо настроить окружение разработки, установить нужный драйвер и настроить соединение между устройством и ПК.

Некоторые веб-сайты могут блокировать автоматические запросы, такие как скрипты, которые использует Selenium. Поэтому, при использовании Selenium следует учитывать этот фактор и применять соответствующие методы для обхода блокировок, например, задержки между запросами или использование прокси-серверов.

Comment: Возможно ли настроить среду без ПК?

Comment: да, и еще можно арендовать услуги как сервис.

Comment: Я не нашел никакой информации, как настроить селениум на андроид. Все сходится к тому чтобы я использовал ПК.

Comment: вот же http://selendroid.io/